# Not able to run my App both on simulator and device, crashes without any error

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I am getting a weird problem while running my App on Simulator as well as on the real device.

I am using Xcode version 6.1.1 on OS X 10.10.1, while running my app it loads the Launch Screen and gets crash without any error.

This problem is on simulator as well as on real device also.

I tried resetting contents and settings in simulator and even deleting the simulator and recreating it again in Xcode, but neither of them worked.

I browse through google and stack overflow but did not find the solution.

If I am trying with other examples its working fine.

In my app I am storing some data from server to document directory, Is the issue is because of this or there is something that I am missing.

Its surely not the Xcode problem I guess!

I am stucked from last 3 days, PLEASE HELP!!

Comment: Check it by adding `Exception Breakpoints`. In Xcode, `Debug -> Breakpoints -> Create Exception Breakpoint`.

Comment: I created Exception Breakpoint but nothing show up.

Comment: Put breakpoint on your `root view controller`, then step through each line.

Comment: Put a break point in 'didFinishLaunchingWithOptions' in your AppDelegate.m and step the breakpoints till you see the crash. Should give you some info.

Comment: I put breakpoint in my root view controller and also in AppDelegate.m `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method but neither of them worked. The control is not going in AppDelegate file itself.

Answer (score 1):

Please identify the problem or provide crash log.
Maybe it's because of sending messages to deallocated objects.

You can check this by turning on Zombie objects.

`Product -> Scheme -> Edit Scheme -> Run -> Enable Zombie Objects`

Comment: After Enabling Zombie Objects I got an error message while running on device saying `App Installation Failed`, An unknown error has occurred. Then I checked the device log and following error/warning show up:     Dec 24 15:35:01 iPhone com.apple.launchd[1] (UIKitApplication:com.teclever.ESBApps[0x2d4c]) <Notice>: (UIKitApplication:com.teclever.ESBApps[0x2d4c]) Throttling respawn: Will start in 2147483647 seconds
Dec 24 15:35:01 iPhone kernel[0] <Debug>: launchd[2933] Builtin profile: container (sandbox). Sorry I don`t have much reputation to add Screen Shot.

Comment: Hi there, my problem is that I am not able to run my App both on simulator and on device. In simulator it loads Launch Screen and after some time screen goes dark. It then returns back. In device when I install it using Xcode it shows above mentioned error message. But I can see the App launch Icon. While tapping on the Icon, it shows black screen and returns back. Please Help!! It was working fine before and now suddenly its stop working while other apps are working fine.

Comment: Ok, try another options: 
-- check deployment target (both at project and target). Are they same or actual?
-- check libraries and frameworks, maybe some of them were corrupted. Delete links from Build Phrases and add again.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Breakpoint Navigator ( using **⌘ 7**)
On bottom left click the "+" button and select "Add Exception Breakpoint"

In your Breakpoint list, you will see a "All Exceptions" added.

Launch your app and Xcode should stop where the exception is raised.